# ImageJ/Fiji change the default colormap

Tags: imagej, colormap, fiji

Is there a way to change the default colormap in ImageJ/Fiji?
Maybe it is too obvious but I didnt spot it in the options.
Or is there a way to run a script automatically after an image has been opened and the script does for example: run("Fire") ?

Cheers

Johannes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to use this macro to open a file and change the LUT/colormap.

```
macro "Open Image As Fire" {
    path = File.openDialog("Select a File");
    open(path);
    run("Fire");
}
```